# GUI in design page and GUI when RUN is not the same (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jpanel, jcomponent

I want to manage the position of component in GUI by easily drag and drop them at design page of Eclipse. This is the GUI I see in design page.(Right click>Test/Preview)

[image: Design page]

I think after I finish rearrange the component in design page, it will look similar when I RUN the app. But, this GUI appear.
[image: After run]

The different appearance make me very hard to adjust the component, for example the width of DAY 2, the height of Medication, DOB : and the green background.
Please let me know if there is any solution to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) (not GridLayout).  (Side note:  if Male and Female shouldn't both be checked at the same time, they should be radio buttons in a single ButtonGroup, not checkboxes.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GridLayout where each day is a column and the subjects(diagnosis, treatment and so on) are the rows. And you create a composite in each grid cell (like Day1 & diagnosis) which contains your buttons for this day and the subject.

[EDIT]
My suggested implementation is: (SWT.BORDER marks all cells of the toplevel grid)

```
    GridLayout topLevelLayout = new GridLayout();
    topLevelLayout.numColumns = 4;
    parent.setLayout(topLevelLayout);

    // head row
    Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    label.setText("Activity");
    label = new Label(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    label.setText("Day 1");
    label = new Label(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    label.setText("Day 2");
    label = new Label(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    label.setText("Day 3");

    // new row - first cell
    label = new Label(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    label.setText("Diagnosis");

    // Day1 & Diagnosis
    GridLayout cellLayout = new GridLayout();
    cellLayout.numColumns = 2;
    Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    composite.setLayout(cellLayout);
    Button button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    button.setText("ECG");
    button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    button.setText("Blood Pressure");
    button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    button.setText("Vital signs");
    // other subjects of diagnosis at day 1...

    // Day2 & Diagnosis
    composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    // same layout like for day1 & diagnosis
    composite.setLayout(cellLayout);
    button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    button.setText("ECG");
    button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    button.setText("Labs");
    button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    button.setText("Blood pressure");
    // other subjects of diagnosis at day 2...

    // Day3 & Diagnosis
    composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    // same layout like for day1 & diagnosis
    composite.setLayout(cellLayout);
    button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    button.setText("Stress Tests");
    button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    button.setText("Labs");
    button = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    button.setText("Cardiac rhythm");
    // other subjects of diagnosis at day 1...

    label = new Label(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    label.setText("Treatment");
```

Comment: I already use GridLayout but it doesnt work.   May I know how to use composite in each grid cell?

Comment: I mean you have a toplevel GridLayout for the headrow and one row for each activity and then you use a second grid for the cells which has two columns.

Comment: Oh.. Yes, I did a another new panel and set to GridLayout for each activity and day but it still show different when running..

Comment: Would add some code of your implementation to your question?

Comment: If you are using Gridlayout and you still have the problem, you may have the wrong padding on some of your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Things like this happen with any designer. Usually they are an indicator of a location change occuring at runtime as the result of a dynamic parameter of some kind. Make sure that you having the correct padding on each of the buttons, and whatever you are using to contain the buttons in should be using a consistent spacing for each one. Also make sure that alignment within the containers is correct, and that both your buttons and the containers they are in are properly anchored.

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to hand code the GUI.

Comment: Ive heard this argument many times, and in my experience it comes mostly from people who have minimal experience with GUI design. Granted for a design this simple handcoding is probably fine, but you still have the same trial and error sort problem of trying to see where things will end up. It virtually always ends up being more time consuming, and not at all easier. It is pretty equal in difficulty level, but much faster with a GUI builder. Subject to the quality of the GUI builder for example. But anything as mature as this should be very good.